# Where is .. defined?

Tags: haskell, enums, enumeration, typeclass, definition

I'm just wondering whether `..` is actually defined in Haskell code anywhere, like in [the Prelude](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/standard-prelude.html)?    Is `enumFromTo` the same thing?  I don't get which is the definition?

```
enumFromTo x y  =  map toEnum [fromEnum x .. fromEnum y]

[ e1 .. e3 ]  =  enumFromTo e1 e3
```

Comment: How would you define it's postfix form? It is not a function that accepts a number and returns a finite range spanning up to this number.

Comment: @bipll Ok, I took away the parentheses.

Comment: Regardless parentheses, `a ..` is a valid expression, and it is not a function, likewise `a, a + 3 ..`. How would you define them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's a part of the *syntax*, specified in the Report, [section 3.10](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html).

Yes it gets translated into code using `enumFrom` etc. functions:

[image]

To your edit of the question: the definitions you show are "default definitions" in the `Enum` typeclass. It says so right there in the Prelude you linked:

```hs
class  Enum a  where
    succ, pred       :: a -> a
    toEnum           :: Int -> a
    fromEnum         :: a -> Int
    enumFrom         :: a -> [a]             -- [n..]
    enumFromThen     :: a -> a -> [a]        -- [n,n'..]
    enumFromTo       :: a -> a -> [a]        -- [n..m]
    enumFromThenTo   :: a -> a -> a -> [a]   -- [n,n'..m]

        -- Minimal complete definition:
        --      toEnum, fromEnum
--             _______                                      -- ____
-- NOTE: these default methods only make sense for types    -- **** NB
--   that map injectively into Int using fromEnum
--  and toEnum.
    succ             =  toEnum . (+1) . fromEnum
    pred             =  toEnum . (subtract 1) . fromEnum
    enumFrom x       =  map toEnum [fromEnum x ..]
    enumFromTo x y   =  map toEnum [fromEnum x .. fromEnum y]
    enumFromThen x y =  map toEnum [fromEnum x, fromEnum y ..]
    enumFromThenTo x y z = 
                        map toEnum [fromEnum x, fromEnum y .. fromEnum z]
```

So each type `a` that is *in* `Enum` must provide the definitions for at least `toEnum :: Int -> a` and `fromEnum :: a -> Int`. If it doesn't provide its own definition for e.g. `enumFromTo :: a -> a -> [a]` then its default definition will be used:

```
enumFromTo :: a -> a -> [a]
enumFromTo x  y   =  map  toEnum  [fromEnum x .. fromEnum y ]
--        └a┘└a┘                           └a┘           └a┘
--                                 └──Int────┘   └──Int────┘
--                       └Int->a┘ └─────────[Int]───────────┘
--                   └───────────────[a]────────────────────┘
```

And for the `Int` type itself there is a *specific* definition defined somewhere in the library, so the default definition of `enumFromTo` is not used for `Int`, thus there is no vicious circle.