# How does haskell break a list in a pattern for head function

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

While learning haskell I couldn't understand how haskell was automatically able to match a pattern where the head of a list is extracted.

```hs
head' :: [a] -> a  
head' [] = error "Can't find head in an Empty list!" 
-- How does haskell break the list into x(first) and xs(rest)? 
head' (x:xs) = x
```

I had read that `[1,2,3]` is syntactical sugar for `1:2:3:[]`.
So `:` is a function that takes any argument and add to the right hand argument?
And how does the list explode backward into two variables head and rest?
`[1,2,3] --> (x:xs)`??

```hs
colon_operator :: a -> [a]
-- not sure how the function would look
```

Sorry if I couldn't explain my question concisely, I am not that great at haskell.

Comment: Are you familiar at all with algebraic data types? If so, the quick answer is that `:` is not an ordinary function but the list constructor; lists are effectively defined as `data [a] = (:) a [a] | []`.

Comment: Is your question about _how_ in terms of compilator implements the logic? Or about how the language is defined? It is not super clear what it is that puzzles you... Or is it that you wat an introduction to pattern matching in general?

Comment: @bradrn wow I didn't know that. What is that `|` doing? Is it like an `if/else`?  I have only seen single `|` in list comprehensions.

Comment: @LudvigH I was wondering how the list when fed to the function automatically knows what `x` and `xs` should be. And also a basic understanding of how `[]` and `:` operator is working in haskell. It would be great if you have some sort of documentation to explain the internals of patterns matching as well. But the initial question was just to know how `[1,2,3] --> (x:xs)` automatically happens.

Comment: @SukhinderpalMann This is a definition of an algebraic data type. You can learn more about them in any Haskell tutorial, e.g. http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses. (I should note though that my definition is not syntactically valid Haskell, and was only intended as an example: a better version would be `data List a = Cons a (List a) | Nil`.)

Comment: `[1,2,3]` is syntactical sugar for `1:2:3:[]` which *actually* is  `1:(2:(3:[]))` which is `(x:xs)` where `x = 1` and `xs = (2:(3:[]))`. so there's no "backward" "explosion" nay *destructuring* here. each `:` has *two* fields to it. that's it.

Comment: @WillNess my imperative programming habits and brain that's used to too much syntactical sugar couldn't see through this `1:(2:(3:[]))`. Thank you. Unrelated to OP does it mean that `[1..3]` the `..` is an operator which is also a function?

Comment: let me find a link for you.... e.g. [here's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63695315/849891) an answer by me with links and some verbiage.

Comment: I've posted my comment as an answer, as is should have been. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caveat lector: this is a zeroth approximation, and wrong in many ways, but at least it's a zeroth approximation!

Using pseudocode, when you call `[]` or `:`, a new data structure is created. Here's how you might write the structure in an imperative language:

```
structure {
    int constructor
    ptr head
    ptr tail
} list
```

When you write `empty = []`, that allocates a new `list`, and populates it this way:

```
empty = alloc(list)
empty.constructor = 0 // 0 means we used [] to construct this
```

The `head` and `tail` pointers are left uninitialized, because they aren't used. When you write `not_empty = 3 : [4]`, that allocates a new `list`, and populates it this way:

```
// three is a pointer to 3
// four is a pointer to [4]
not_empty = alloc(list)
not_empty.constructor = 1 // 1 means we used : to construct this
not_empty.head = three
not_empty.tail = four
```

Now, when you pattern match on a list, that corresponds to checking the `constructor` field. So if you write, say:

```
case not_empty of
    [] -> 7
    x:xs -> 20 + x
```

Then what happens imperatively is something like this:

```
if not_empty.constructor == 0
    return 7
elseif not_empty.constructor == 1
    return 20 + dereference(not_empty.head)
endif
```

(Similarly, if you had mentioned `xs`, it would dereference the `tail` pointer.)

Between constructing `list` structures and pattern matching on them, you now know the basic building blocks used to build *every* function on lists! At the most basic level, those are the only two `list`-y things you can do.

Comment: Thank you! I wish there were more such samples to compare functional code against traditional imperative code written in C/C++. By any chance if you know some document where I can see comparison/similar implementations in C/C++ or inner workings of basic haskell functions/behaviors it would be great! This helped me, haskell's type inference and pattern matching blows my mind, I have started haskell only 1 week ago.

Comment: @SukhinderpalMann [Implementing lazy functional languages on stock hardware:
the Spineless Tagless G-machine](https://twister.43foldrs.com/spineless-tagless-gmachine.pdf) is an excellent introduction to compiling Haskell. It's very approachable, and discusses the actual technology behind older versions of GHC. (They actually discuss *two* implementation methods, and they've since switched from the one discussed in detail there to the one they gloss over.)

Comment: The comparison can be against any other popular language, not an issue. I might be committing a sin but I have seen some crazy FP(not truly FP) libraries/frameworks written in JS like Elm, faylang, etc. They are tempting just so that I can have something to side-by-side compare to understand the haskell/FP code better.

Answer (score 1):

`[1,2,3]` is syntactical sugar for `1:[2,3]`, which is ...

... `(x:xs)` where `x = 1` and  `xs = [2,3]`.

So there's no "backward" "explosion" nay *destructuring* here.

Each `:` has *two* fields to it. That's it.